# Calculating margin and bias for SVM's

Tags: svm

I apologise for the newbishness of this question in advance but I am stuck. I am trying to solve this question,

[image]

I can do parts i)-1v) but I am stuck on v. I know to calculate the margin y, you do

```
y=2/||W||
```

and I know that W is the normal to the hyperplane, I just don't know how to calculate it. Is this always

`W=[1;1]` ?

Similarly, the bias, `W^T * x + b = 0`

how do I find the value `x` from the data points? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was just going through this question, so how would we solve it now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Consider building an SVM over the (very little) data set shown in Picture for an example like this, the maximum margin weight vector will be parallel to the shortest line connecting points of the two classes, that is, the line between  and , giving a weight vector of . The optimal decision surface is orthogonal to that line and intersects it at the halfway point. Therefore, it passes through . So, the SVM decision boundary is:

[image]

Working algebraically, with the standard constraint that  , we seek to minimize  . This happens when this constraint is satisfied with equality by the two support vectors. Further we know that the solution is  for some . So we have that:

[image]

Therefore a=2/5 and b=-11/5,  and . So the optimal hyperplane is given by

[image]
and b= -11/5 .
The margin boundary is

[image]

This answer can be confirmed geometrically by examining picture.